# creating a set in ZIMPL (which creates .LP for SoPlex & CPLEX)

Tags: linear-programming

I am looking for some help creating a set dynamically in ZIMPL.

I have a parameter table:

```
param Q[W*W]  :=  |1,2,3,4,5|                                                                                         
                |1|1,1,0,0,0|                                                                                         
                |2|1,1,0,0,0|                                                                                         
                |3|0,0,1,0,0|                                                                                         
                |4|0,0,0,1,0|                                                                                         
                |5|0,0,0,0,1|;
```

I can access elements like: Q[1,2] --> 1, Q[3,3] --> 1, Q[3,4] --> 0.

What I want to do is create a function that, given a row index, returns me the column indices that have a value of 1.  Like, func(Q,2) would return {1,2}.  And func(Q,3) would return {3}.

I have been struggling with this, I've read the ZIMPL manual, and I can't find the right methods to do this.  I know how to create a function, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually compute the set to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly.  But if your $Q$ is known, you can pre-compute all the output, and store them in a set, with row number as index.

Comment: thanks, I am just precomputing things now